# Interface doesn't get static IP on boot

Tags: access-point

I am trying to set up a Raspberry Pi as a wifi access point. It's going to run a web server which can be accessed with nearby tablets. It is supposed to be bundled with research equipment, and will have no further network connection. It is completely standalone.

When I boot the raspi, the wlan0-interface doesn't get a static IP, which also causes `isc-dhcp-server` to not start. If I do `ifdown wlan0 && ifup wlan0`, it does get it's proper IP set.

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file looks like this:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
#iface wlan0 inet manual
#wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
#iface default inet dhcp

iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.50.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.50.0
broadcast 192.168.50.255
```

I followed [this guide](http://www.maketecheasier.com/set-up-raspberry-pi-as-wireless-access-point/) to set it up.

My wifi-stick is a [Sony IFU-WLM3](https://pro.sony.com/bbsc/ssr/micro-xdcam/cat-broadcastcameras/product-IFUWLM3/)

The setup works if I do `ifdown wlan0 && ifup wlan0` and then restart the dhcp-server.

Why doesn't the IP get set on boot, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Add the lines:

```
wpa-ssid "<name of wireless network>"
wpa-psk "<password of wireless network>"
```

after `broadcast 192.168.50.255`

Comment: Didn't work. Also, this is in my hostapd.conf-file. I don't see why I need it in the interfaces-file too

Comment: Sorry. It was my mistake. I forgot about hostapd. According to [this guide](http://seravo.fi/2014/create-wireless-access-point-hostapd) you have to add this line   `hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`